# Need a quick JavaScript/jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 17000 line page with lots of HTML/JavaScript/jQuery and it's always frustrating when I make a typo and there's no clue when the page  loads into the browser what the problem is.  It just - doesn't do anything.  Consider the patch of code below, for example, where the third line terminates with a ' instead of a ; .

```
$(document).on('click', 'input#answer_chkbx', function(e) {
     if(e.target.checked){  
    x$ = g.currentElement$.find('.cellContent')'
    g.currentElement$.addClass('answerBox')
                 .css('background-color','tansparent')
             .height(25)
            .width(150);
     }
});
```

There should be something that runs through the code and finds that immediately.

Is there a way to check for things like this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the first clue is the syntax highlighting, see that?

Comment: Another clue should be the error messages in your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: You can see syntax errors in the error console.

Comment: Do you ever run your code through jsLint?

Comment: elclanrs - Yes I see it if I'm looking there.  But I may have just done 10 minutes of editing in 5 different areas of the code, and now something in there is broken.

Comment: Goleztrol - I'm using Firefox so I assume that would be FireBug. But FireBug only takes over once the code compiles/interprets successfully.  This code didn't get that far.

Comment: Joe Simmons - What error console are you talking about?

Comment: jfriend00 - jsLint seems to require you to paste a complete JavaScript program. If I paste just segment I get all kinds of errors like "$ used before being declared," and the scanning gives up and stops.

Comment: @Steve - the answer to you here is to figure out how to use tools that are out there.  Your browser's error console or debug console will show you JS parse errors.  Tools like jsLint will show you possible programming mistakes.  Those tools can be used with external libraries with the right settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider a tool such as [`JSLint`](http://www.jslint.com/) or [`JSHint`](http://jshint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For offline coding you can use [Netbeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/74/index.html) or [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/tr/products/dreamweaver.html)

Comment: I use Dreamweaver.  Where does it tell you you left a ";" off the end of a JavaScript line?